# Default value for type parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

I'm failing to figure out how (if at all) you can set a default value for a *type*-parameter in Scala.
Currently I have a method similar to this:

```
def getStage[T <: Stage](key: String): T = {
  // Do fancy stuff that returns something
}
```

But what I'd like to do is provide an implementation of `getStage` that takes no value for `T` and uses a default value instead. I tried to just define another method and overload the parameters, but it only leads to one of the methods being completely overriden by the other one. If I have not been clear what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
def getStage[T<:Stage = Stage[_]](key: String): T = {

}
```

I hope it's clear what I'm asking for. Does anyone know how something like this could be achieved?

Comment: How will `getStage` return a value of type `T` (given that `T` could be any suitable type)?  Presumably you'd have to use `asInstanceOf` or similar, which is usually undesirable. Could you explain a bit more about how this code would be called, and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Well chances are that I'm doing things completely wrong as I haven't become that used to the Scala way of doing things yet... The class the `getStage` method is defined on manages a `Map[String,SyncStage]` instance variable. I intended to use matching to make sure that the object is of the expected class (so no need for `asInstanceOf`) and raise an error otherwise (it should never happen because key isn't a runtime specified variable). I have an alternative ready to avoid this whole thing alltogether, but I wondered if it is possible because I've already been in another similar situation...

Comment: There isn't such a thing as a default type parameter. It may be possible to work around with type constraints, but it might be better to avoid this.

Comment: @m-z I don't see any reason to suggest avoiding this if you're using type classes to guide the inference of the parameter. Sure, you can get into situations where the implicit resolution rules are confusing, but it's still often a reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can do this kind of thing in a type-safe way using type classes. For example, suppose you've got this type class:

```
trait Default[A] { def apply(): A }
```

And the following type hierarchy:

```
trait Stage
case class FooStage(foo: String) extends Stage
case class BarStage(bar: Int) extends Stage
```

And some instances:

```
trait LowPriorityStageInstances {
  implicit object barStageDefault extends Default[BarStage] {
    def apply() = BarStage(13)
  }
}

object Stage extends LowPriorityStageInstances {
  implicit object stageDefault extends Default[Stage] {
    def apply() = FooStage("foo")
  }
}
```

Then you can write your method like this:

```
def getStage[T <: Stage: Default](key: String): T =
  implicitly[Default[T]].apply()
```

And it works like this:

```
scala> getStage("")
res0: Stage = FooStage(foo)

scala> getStage[BarStage]("")
res1: BarStage = BarStage(13)
```

Which I think is more or less what you want.

Comment: Thank you. :) Tbh it seems a bit more complicated than I expected it to be, but I guess I just need to get some more used to the concept of type classes.

Comment: Yeah, Scala's encoding of type classes is kind of verbose, but once you get used to it it's not as complicated as it looks.

Comment: Great answer. Would you share a link to more information about `T <: Stage: Default` (double type parameter?) I never saw before, please?

Comment: @wipman It's not really a double type parameter but I agree it is a bit cryptic if you have not seen it before. Best to look at it in two parts: The first part `T <: Stage` is called an [upper type bound](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/upper-type-bounds.html) - meaning type variable `T` refers to a subtype of type `Stage`. The second part is called a [context bound](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/context-bounds.html) which is syntactic sugar for `def getStage[T <: Stage](key: String)(implicit d: Default[Stage]): T =...`